# Using @Rule for PowerMock initialisation crashes Log4J?

Tags: java, junit, log4j, mockito, powermock

I used to have `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` in my annotations, but I now want to use `@RunWith(NamedParameterized.class)`, so I tried to do add a new `@Rule` to the code so it looked like this:

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule mRule = new PowerMockRule();

@Rule
public PersistentTest mTestRule = new PersistentTest("10_000");
```

But then I tried to run the test and I got:

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader@73a34b] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "StdOut".
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d7fdec9, pid=13460, tid=14952
#
# JRE version: 6.0_35-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.10-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xdec9]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# hs_err_pid13460.log
```

I know that initializing the PowerMock with `@Rule` is a problematic thing, but is there anything to override this problem? Or another way to use `NamedParametrized.class`?

Comment: Not an answer, as not "helping" with your question; but still imporant ...
My "rule number 1" for PowerMock: "try never using it". We found in our work that "I need PowerMock to test this piece of code" usually translates to "this piece of code is poorly designed and should be reworked". PowerMock can have negative impact on your test environment; as it can break your ability to measure coverage for example.

Comment: @EddyG - that's what I hear before. In our work we are trying to use it for what it was ment for, but still, even if there is a single good reason to use the PowerMock - it is allways a pain in the class.

Comment: Off-topic: Where does the NamedParametrized runner come from?